# I have problem with Jest testing vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, jestjs

I am trying to test with Jest my vue Component in witch is implemented bootstrap.

This is my test for VoteComponent:

`

```
import VoteComponent from '../../src/components/VoteComponent.vue'

import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue/src/index'

import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';

const localVue = createLocalVue();

localVue.use(BootstrapVue);

describe('VoteComponent', () => 
{
    test('is a Vue instance', () => 
{
        const wrapper = mount(VoteComponent, {localVue})

        expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy()
    })

})
```

`

This is what terminal shows when I run my test:

Details:

```
C:\...\...\...\...\...\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css:7
:root {
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

  72 | 
  73 | <script>
> 74 |     import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
     | ^
  75 |     import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
  76 |     import VueFlip from 'vue-flip';
  77 |     import fontawesome from "@fortawesome/fontawesome";
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. you should be more precise in your question to maximize the chance to have a valuable answer. See [ask]

Comment: .css aren't valid JS modules, there should be a loader for them, this is commonly handled by Webpack. It's unknown how you configured and run Jest but it obviously wasn't configured to import css files.